# RegExr to match URL var up to & or #

Tags: regex

So I have a URL like this:

> http://www.someurl.com/subdir/dir/name?**urlVar=true**#someotherpath/td/a/way/p/data/1612040?menu=menu1&test=mytest&test=two

I'm trying to write a regExr to get my `urlVar`, but I've only gotten as far as this: `[!?&]urlVar=([^&#]+)(&|$)`

If I remove the `#` in the expression above I get this:

```
urlVar=true#someotherpath/td/a/way/p/data/1612040?menu=menu1&
```

But I want it to stop at the *pound sign*. Adding the *pound* in the `[^&]` capture group doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I've rollback my edit sorry my bad for that edit @ndn

Comment: Do tell your programming language please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^?&]+\?urlVar=([^&#]+)(?:&|#)?.*`

---

`[^?&]+\?` - should read any character which is not `?` or `&` up to `?`.

`([^&#]+)` - should capture value.

`(?:&|#)?.*` - should read fallowing `&` or `#`, if exists (but not capture that), and any character after.

---

But I would rather replace second group with character class: `[^?&]+\?urlVar=([^&#]+)[&#]?.*`

You can validate it [here](http://fiddle.re/x0hfh6) or [here](https://regex101.com/r/zU8pY6/1).

Comment: Hvala Elvedine! Majstor!

Comment: @Amir Nema na cemu, zemljak.

Answer (score 1):

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
urlVar=[^#]+(?=#|$)
```

What this means is match `urlVar=`, followed by multiple characters that are not `#` and end the match when you reach a `#` character or the end of the string.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/cQ5yY6/1)

---

If you use a non-javascript regex engine, it probably supports lookbehinds too.

Therefore, you can extract only the **true** part without the `urlVar=`:

```
(?<=urlVar=)[^#]+(?=#|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not matching in your regex:

```regex
[!?&]urlVar=([^&#]+)(&|$)
                    ^^^^^
```

- It's not followed by a "`&`" nor the end of string.

Simply remove that construct and it will work:

```regex
[!?&]urlVar=([^&#]+)
```